# How to limit user's access to Redshift to row-level?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I know that SQL Server is actually supports Row-Level Security

Therefore, user can only access records that allows to see.

```
So User John can only access records for Client's Toyota, Mazda, and Nissan

User Lisa can only access records for clients Ford, and GM
```

Now my new company is using AWS Redshift datawarehouse and we have a problem of controling people's access to the data warehouse.

We do not have a data specialist in Redshift and I have to roll the sleeve and do it myself without proper Redshift expereince.

so here i am asking my question.

Is it possible to limit user's access to redshift to the row-level? and how to do it?

Comment: AFAIK Redshift doesn't support Row-Level-Security natively at this point, there are some workarounds, but none of them are very efficient as Redshift is a column-oriented data store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can restrict access to rows by using `CREATE VIEW` and adding a `WHERE` clause.

For example:

```sql
CREATE VIEW john_records AS
SELECT * FROM records
WHERE client in ('Toyota', 'Mazda', 'Nissan')
```

Or, if you have a table that maps the relationships, you could use:

```sql
CRETE VIEW records_view AS
SELECT * FROM records
WHERE client in (SELECT clients from map_table WHERE user = CURRENT_USER)
```

Then, revoke access to the table for these users and grant access to the View. This way, they always have to query the data via the View, which will restrict the rows they can access.

Comment: how to pass the CURRENT_USER to the view? is CURRENT_USER is a shared variable ?

Comment: Yes: [CURRENT_USER - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CURRENT_USER.html)